# Rider is not opening browser on running playwright unit tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, rider, playwright-sharp

I am trying to run my tests in Playwright cucumber tests and my tests are running fine in headless mode but it's not launching the browser with this .runSettings configuration

browser.runsettings

```
`<LaunchOptions>
    <Headless>false</Headless>
    <Channel>chrome</Channel>
 </LaunchOptions>`
```

However, I am able to launch the browser in VScode by running playwright cucumber tests. Any idea?

I've configured a custom runSettings file with LaunchOptions in unit test runner settings in the rider.
Chrome is enabled in Web browsers and Preview.

Comment: I have the same problem, appearently there is/was bug relating to the runsettings file. If you find out how to do this please tell me.